# query properites from promise object and save in variable

Tags: typescript, promise, axios, factory-pattern

I am using an axios get request, and returning an object of `response.data`.But i want to be able to query the properties of `response.data` and save those as variables and use it in another class.

```js
export class myClass {
    public async getData() {
        return axios.get(url)
            .then(response => response.data)
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
```

I want to access these properties from the response, and save as values:

```js
response.data.name
response.data.address
response.data.company
```

I can console log the properties, but if i try to use it as a value somewhere, i get undefined.

```js
public async getName() {
    return this.getData().then((response: any) => {
        console.log(response.data.name);
        return response.data.name;
    });
}
```

Call :

```
const name = new myClass().getName();
NAME: name(undefined)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `async` function returns a `Promise`, you should implement it that way, more understandable :

**myClass**

```js
export class myClass {
    ...
    public async getData() {
        return axios.get(url);
    }

    public async getName() {
        try {
            const response = await this.getData();
            return response.data.name;
        } catch (error) {
            // handle errors here
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**call to getName()**

```js
const myClass = new myClass();
const name = await myClass.getName();
```

Comment: when calling the getName i get the following error:
`const name = await myClass.getName();`, i get error: 
`await' expression is only allowed within an async function`

Comment: Forgot about `getData()` function, I'll edit my post

Comment: where `const name = await myClass.getName();` is called ? If it is in a function, you'll need to prefix with `async`

Comment: even when in a function, I still get undefined

Comment: as it says in the error message, you can only use `await` expression inside a `async` function. You should add more details about where `const name = await myClass.getName();` is used

Comment: how can i access and use the value of `response.data.name` without it being in an async function?